# How to turn the built-in retina display of MacBook Pro into an external monitor?

Tags: mac, display

I have an external Retina display, which is teared down from another Retina MacBook Pro, the display works well. Now I would like to use the external Retina display as an external monitor. Is there any way to make it happen? Thanks.

I didn't try anything, because I totally have no any idea on this.

Comment: It's likely impossible or too much work. If I were you, I'd sell the display assembly on eBay and buy an external monitor

Comment: This is not something I would tackle, and I've seen inside a computer more times than I can count. It's not _impossible_, but it'd be way too much effort involved, not to mention you'd most likely have to be very patient tracking down someone who could customise the cabling you'd need, etc. Instead, the suggestion by @NoahL to sell it on eBay will get you some money and you can just move on.

Comment: NoahL @Monomeeth Thanks for your suggestions, sir. You are right. After a research, I found it really took lots of work to make it happen. I'll try to sell it and buy a real monitor.